# Trigger a Jenkins Build based on Commit Author?

Tags: git, jenkins

The team I work on has 4 developers.  The desired workflow is for each developer to have their own jenkins project and for any branch they push to, to trigger a build.  It doesn't look like it's possible from the Git plugin, and there doesn't seem to be a way to select a branch based on the set of commit authors.  It seems like we could come up with magic branch names and trigger each team member's project based on the branch name, but a branch might be passed around to multiple developers to work on a large issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option in the Git plugin to do the opposite = exclude a list of users:

[image]

As your team is quite small (4 developers), you can exclude 3 developers in order to build the commits of the 4th one.

Comment: This solution is a little annoying, but it does work.  Hadn't thought of this.  Worse case scenario here is that even for a large team, you could script creating this list provided the SCM has some way of polling users (which bitbucket does.)

Comment: If you are using Bitbucket server, you can install this plugin to trigger Jenkins for specific users (using the user filter): https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/de.aeffle.stash.plugin.stash-http-get-post-receive-hook/server/overview

Comment: Does "user" in this _Additional Behaviour_ really refer to the _author_ or is it the _commiter_?

Comment: @GeroldBroser I think it's for the committer.

Comment: @ThomasTu Did you confuse _author_ with _committer_ at "_based on the set of commit authors_" in your question then?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for a combination of:

#### [`git-show-ref`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref)

```
  $ git show-ref [--hash]
  528ea2bb0d2f9dbf166bcefce2aba34cf53cdf4d [refs/heads/branch]
  a3a5a0d105729c19dfea0aa09a8c8a19a9d65262 [refs/heads/master]
```

and:

#### [`git-log`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

for each of the branches:

```
  (master)$ git log [--author|--committer]=... --pretty="%H"
  a3a5a0d105729c19dfea0aa09a8c8a19a9d65262
  18c4c551a935cfa42189fc48f83273a3290c96b0
  86fd09697424a72bbece451bc6bdab54cee61794
  d7aaab0f4d4055bc541284b723edb111c55b3e95

  (branch)$ git log [--author|--committer]=... --pretty="%H"
  528ea2bb0d2f9dbf166bcefce2aba34cf53cdf4d
  d7aaab0f4d4055bc541284b723edb111c55b3e95
```

And, tadaaa, here's [**`git-reflog`**](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog):

```
(master)$ git reflog [--author|--committer]=... --pretty="%H [%gd]" --branches -<no of branches>
a3a5a0d105729c19dfea0aa09a8c8a19a9d65262 [master@{0}]
528ea2bb0d2f9dbf166bcefce2aba34cf53cdf4d [branch@{0}]
```